# Maintian user logged in for long time

Tags: asp.net

I want to know how I can code for maintaining user logged in for long time. Currently for user authentication and maintain logging status , I am using Session on master page , but my session expires in a short period of time.  I have seen in many sites like gmail, facebbok, stackoverflow and so many sites.Once A user logged in ,he/she can you site for a couple of time without logging again.

Comment: you can try FormsAuthentication and set persistent cookies

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your site only gets a few hundred visitors per week it would be sufficient to just increase the timeout of the session.

If your site is a little busier, increasing the session timeout will fill up a lot of memory that could be used for other things, especially if you store a lot in the session.  For the session to work and remain logged in, the session that matches the session token in the cookie set in the user's browser needs to exist.

One good reason sessions expire is to get rid of sessions taking up memory that belong to that visitor to your site who never comes back or the search engine bot that doesn't need a session anyway.

To compensate for this issue, sites like Facebook and Google store a long hashed token in a cookie in your browser.  They save this token (or a hashed version of it) on their server and associate it with your user account, so when you come back the server knows it's you and it can create a brand new session for you (assuming FB/Google use sessions).

So, in summary, generate a cookie (make sure it's domain limited and secure if you're using SSL and such) that contains a long string of random text.  Save that random text (or a hash of it) in your database along with the user id it belongs to.  Each time that user visits your site and doesn't have a session created, compare that cookie's value with the database and if it matches one of the rows, log the user in.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Valuable Answer . As I have read out Using session for long time take to much memory and reduce site speed. As from your post I got that make a cookie table with (Cookie id ,userid, expiration time and..) . on user first time logging insert cookie with userid in table as well as in user browser. When User revisit and open the site page check the row as per userid and than allow user to login . From this we can also handle logout (expiration time) i.e by one weak. How I will be storing cookie on browser , how to read cookie from brower for checking it exist or not.

Comment: I suppose this depends on what server-side language you're using.  Lots of people like PHP these days so here's a page that describes how that language handles cookies: http://php.net/manual/en/features.cookies.php.  You'll use setcookie() to write and $_COOKIE to read.  Typically every scripting language has a very similar manifestation of the exact same thing, so they'll all work pretty much that same way.

Comment: OK I got how to read and write cookie from browser.I have some more doubts like are they safe, does all browser support them, how to pass userid(extracted from cookie from database) to differnt pages .Using cookie to get Userid on index page load make effect on speed or on performance? For authentication what I can store in cookie like userid,expiration time and otherss like???

Comment: You're using cookies in your session anyway, that's how your session is identified, so it's not going to be any less supported than your session.  It will hurt your performance much less than having 100,000 zombie sessions.  Don't store user_id, store a really long token that you generate that you've linked with the user id.  Cookies can be edited by the user but they are still secure when you use a token.   Set the expiration time to 5 years from now so it never logs them out, make sure the https flag is set if you're on a secure site.

Answer (score 0):

Sessionstate timeout property is mentioned in minutes.

In webconfig file...

```
<system.web>
.......
<sessionState timeout="1440"></sessionState>

</system.web>
```

The session will get expired if the webform is idle for 24 hrs continuously.

You can have this sessionstate block only within

```
  <system.web>
```

See http://msdn2.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h6bb9cz9%28vs.80%29.aspx for more details.

Comment: I tried this one earlier on one of my site. Some time it works well but some time Session expires before the time limit.

Answer (score 0):

Yes as @benjamin said, keep your timeouts low. Really low. As low as say 5 minutes. This way you will not end up hogging the server memory. To keep the currrent session alive, use Javascript `setInterval` to poll the server every 3-4 minutes, or use `slidingExpiration="true"` in your web.config.

For re-visiting users, (if you find difficulty in implementing @benjamin's suggestion) then another alternative is to have a "remember me" check box on the login page. Just reuse the `FormsAuthentication` cookie manually:

```vb
If allIsWell Then
   FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(userName, isRememberMe)
End IF
```

Where `isRememberMe` is the checkbox value. If true it will set a persistent cookie.

Then in global.asax:

```vb
If HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated Then
   'Recreate user session contents here
End If
```